# how to get values from dropdowns under while loop and store the data in db using php

Tags: java, php, html

Ive been working on a project where the user selects his userame and date range and when clicked on submit, a html table would appear.Now the user would have to fill out a input field(a drop down) in one of the columns and once submit is clicked,the input data should stored in the database accordingly. I managed to get the form (drop down) at the right place but how could i call the data selected and saved to the database.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    include ('connect.php');
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM errorreport WHERE user = '$username' AND date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('cant find data');
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "welcome '$username' \n '$num_rows' results found";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<table border='1' width:'100%'>";
    echo "<tr><th>DATE</th><th>TASK_QUEUE</th><th>AUDIO</th><th>TRANSCRIBED</th><th>VERIFIED</th><th>OVERTURNED_FIELDS</th><th>TYPE OF ERROR</th><th>BLUESHIFT_LINK</th></tr>";
    echo "<form action='insert.php' method='post'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['OVERTURNED_FIELDS'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<select name = error_type>";
    echo "<option value= > </option>
    <option value=Convention Error>Convention Error</option>
    <option value=Listening Error>Listening Error</option>
    <option value=Referencing Error>Referencing Error</option>
    <option value=Spelling/Typos>Spelling/Typos</option>
    <option value=Metadata Error>Metadata Error</option>
    </select>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<a href=".$row['BLUESHIFT_LINK'].">Click Here </a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type=submit value=submit>";
    echo "</form>";
    }

    ?>
```

[please find the photo for a look at the webpage. When i select inputs from each dropdown and click submit at the end of the table, the data is not being saved to the db.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA5DO.jpg)

[I get this error message when i submit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX9j8.jpg)

please find the insert.php code below.

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'testdb');

$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);
if(!$dbcon)
{
    echo 'not connected to server';
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($dbcon,'testdb'))
{
    echo 'database not selected';
}

$errortype = $_POST['error_type'];
$audio=$_POST['audio'];
$username=$_POST['name'];


$sql = "UPDATE errorreport SET error_type = '$errortype'  WHERE user=  '$username' and audio = '$audio'";
if(!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql))
{
    echo 'not inserted';
}
else
{
    echo 'inserted';
}
header("refresh:100; url=select1.php");

?>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Welcome to Error Report Portal </title>
 <style type="text/css">
 table {
     background-color: #FFFACD;
 }
 th {
     width: 150px;
     text-align: center;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Welcome to Error Report Portal! </h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two hidden input field, echo the name and audiolink as a value for the controls. eg.

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;" />
```